# Is it ok to accept cash payments on Airbnb?

Tags: legal, money, airbnb, payment

Both in terms of law and airbnb policies. Can your account be closed f. ex, because you, as a host accepted cash (and for additional circumstance - also asked for it yourself).

Also what about partly cash? Like if I am asked, while travelling, to pay 50% on airbnb and then the rest in cash? ..

Update:
Accepting cash payments seem to be secure as the traveller can pay half and have airbnb security on that side, while still having more security in terms of being able to check the housing and do live transaction. Host in turn can refuse to give keys to somebody of suspect. So in the light of these - does airbnb close accounts on violation, if the only violation is that they were prevented to collect their full part?

Comment: Note that "legal" and "against the terms" aren't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: You're asking about what's permitted by Airbnb's TOS, not what's legal. Different things. It would be legal to accept a belly-dance as part-/full-payment, assuming you both entered into an agreement to do that. But it would almost surely violate their TOS.

Comment: The most obvious reason for this is that Airbnb charges its fees on a percentage basis, so any arrangement where a host is accepting cash is one where they're cutting Airbnb out of the deal. While there are other good reasons for them to prohibit cash payments, they definitely aren't going to allow you to do anything that loses them money.

Comment: When I ran out of credit in my credit card, I contacted AirBNB asking them what should I do ("should I pay in cash? the host needs to get his money!").
They answered within a day and solved this issue.

Comment: How did they solve it?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, your account can be closed if you accept cash. Here's what [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/help/article/126/what-methods-of-payment-does-airbnb-accept) has published on this issue:

> Offline or cash payments are a violation of our Terms of Service, and
>   can result in removal from Airbnb. We prohibit off-site payments
>   because paying outside of Airbnb makes it harder for us to protect
>   your information and puts you at a greater risk of fraud and other
>   security issues.

Comment: Makes sense, but about partly cash payments, is it the same violation? Because the reasoning does not apply anymore..

Comment: I would assume that when Airbnb says "cash payments" they mean all forms. Full, partial, even a penny.

Comment: How does part cash payments "makes it harder for us to protect your information and puts you at a greater risk of fraud and other security issues."? Do they have this as an excuse to make more money or is it a legitimate cause in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer that. Perhaps contacting Airbnb could help?

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I dont want my account closed :DD

Comment: If there's a dispute, Airbnb can easily withhold your payment while taking back cash is not exactly easy / doable.

Comment: Hmm, usually the transaction goes through the first day of the guest, so I dont think its the case

Comment: Also, the guest pays part cash after they meet tge host and see the place, so its more secure for them, not less

Comment: @Aurimas they're still a business and still want to make money, so they won't want you to make any transaction that doesn't involve them, large or small. They want their cut.

Comment: The obvious fraud forbidding cash payments protects against is where the host says on arrival "the price has gone up, you must pay me an extra $50 to stay here". The other one is where host and guest agree to tell AirBnB that the price is $50 (from which AirBnB takes a cut) but that privately another $50 changes hands, from which AirBnB doesn't get a cut.

Comment: By requiring all transactions to go through AirBNB, the host is guaranteed payment, while the guest will not risk surprises in relation to the cost. It of course guarantees AirBNB an income, too.

Comment: I have seen listings explicitly say things like "During winter please pay 300 yen extra at arrival as a heating fee" though. Also, many listings also propose optional services, which is not controversial I guess.

Comment: @Aurimas "protect you" is a euphemism for "protect us".